# Why is textView not showing?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-layout, android-fragments, textview

I made cardView and implemented onClickListener, I also created a fragement the card navigates into which has a textView.. But, when I navigate into the fargement it returns this blank screen;

[image]

Please what's causign this??

Here's the onClickListener code in .kt file;

```
        // ssJkRowling
        val ssJoanneRowling : CardView = view.findViewById(R.id.ss_jk_rowling)
        ssJoanneRowling.setOnClickListener {
            val ssJoanneRowlingFragment = SsJoanneRowlingFragment()
            val transaction: FragmentTransaction? = fragmentManager?.beginTransaction()
            transaction?.replace(R.id.fl_fragment, ssJoanneRowlingFragment)
            transaction?.commit()
        }
```

Here's the cardView in .xml file;

```
                <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                    android:id="@+id/ss_jk_rowling"
                    android:layout_width="250dp"
                    android:layout_height="320dp"
                    app:cardElevation="6dp"
                    app:cardCornerRadius="12dp"
                    android:layout_margin="30dp"
                    android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                    android:layout_columnWeight="1">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="260dp"
                            android:src="@drawable/ss_jk_rowling"
                            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                            android:contentDescription="@string/stories_imageview"/>

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="55dp"
                            android:padding="15dp"
                            android:text="@string/Joanne_Rowling"
                            android:textSize="18sp" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

And Here the textView Code in the fragement the cardView navigates to;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Constraints xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".SsJoanneRowlingFragment">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="15dp"
                android:text="@string/Joanne_Rowling_story" />


        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Constraints>
```

That's a lot for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove `Constraints` from your target's xml layout and use `ScrollView` as parent, it should work:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:padding="15dp"
            android:text="@string/Joanne_Rowling_story" />


    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```